# Extracting Address from Custom Post via Javascript for Google Maps API

Tags: custom-post-types, javascript, google-maps

I am created a theme with custom posts which outputs to a Google Map with place markers. Users will create a custom post users and include street addresses which will be geocoded using Google's Map API v3 and a marker is placed on a Google Map.

I am relatively new to coding and designing custom Wordpress themes, so I am trying to wrap my head around how to grab information from each custom post in javascript for the Google Maps API.

Can someone please explain how this is done?

Thanks,
AME

Comment: see [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64627/geocoding-an-exploded-custom-field-array/64634#64634) for a few hints that may get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is kind of easy..

The google-map API needs a format like `Your Street 123, 54321 Your City`

Assuming you have your data like this:

```
<div id="street">Your Street 123</div>
<div id="zip">54321</div>
<div id="city">Your City</div>
```

Assuming you are using jQuery:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.create_gmap_address = function() {

        var street = $('#street').html();
        var zip = $('#zip').html();
        var city = $('#city').html();

        return street + ',' + zip + ' ' + city;
    }
})(jQuery);
```

And then in your maps API code:

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': $.create_gmap_address() }, function(results, status) {
    // your maps code
```

**Solution 2**

Or you could, of course, get all this data via php and then store into a global JS variable (maybe the better way).

```
function set_address_js_var() {
    if ( 'your_post_type' == get_post_type() ) {
        // Assuming you are using meta fields to store the address
        $postMeta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID());
        return $postMeta['sreet'] . ',' . $postMeta['zip'] . ' ' . $postMeta['city'];
    }
}
function load_fe_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'global-js-var', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my_file.js' );
    $localize_array = array(
        'google_maps_address' => set_address_js_var()
    );
    wp_localize_script( 'global-js-var', 'my_global', $localize_array );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_fe_scripts');
```

You can now acces the var in your JS File by my_global.google_maps_address